# How to fix an WMV file with Audio that grows more out of sync over time?

Tags: video, audio, sync, conversion, wmv

We currently use a DVR that converts to WMV on download.  The files are originally stored as MP4, but it uses a proprietary codec.  So far, I have only found one program that converts the MP4 to WMV, provided by HIKVISION.

The issue is that these files, after conversion, have audio that grows more out of sync over time.  Towards the end of the video, the audio can be several seconds behind the video.

What program(s) would you recommend to get this back in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMV audio sync issues with the frame rate.  While most video would normally be 29.97, WMVs either run at a variable frame rate (VFR) or run at 29.00.  It's very annoying.

So, there's a few things to try.  The first being that if you can avoid using WMV as an intermediate file format, avoid it.

Otherwise....

Try this: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/AsfBin

If that doesn't help, try importing the WMV into windows movie maker, and export as a DV-AVI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I had seen solutions very similar to that on videohelp.   Unfortunately, ASFBIN didn't seem to work.   Thanks for responding!

Comment: I had problems converting old WMV files to MP4 without the audio becoming out of sync, and as a Windows 10 user I didn't think I could install Windows Movie Maker anymore. It turns out that you still can install it, and it worked flawlessly for me